# C++ - Pass Pointer of a Template Class to A Function

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to pass a pointer to a templated object to another class.

```cpp
template <int size>
class A {
public:
    int a[size] = {0};

    int getA(int n) {
       return a[n];
    }
};


class B {
public:
    A<>* b;

    void setB(A<>* n) {
        b = n;
    }
};


int main()
{
    const int size1 = 10;

    A<size1> data1;
    B b1;
    
    b1.setB(&data1);
}
```

Which doesn't work.

As a solution, I can create the B class as a template class and create `B` object as `B<A<size1>> b1;` but this will create multiple objects if I multiply `A<sizeX>`, which I don't want since this code is for an embedded project which has finite resources.

All I want is to pass the pointer of `data1` object to another class function and store it inside. The code I'm looking for is for `C++03`, I cannot use `C++11` features such as shared pointers.

Is there a way to do this?

Appreciate any help,

Comment: And there's no reasonable way to make `class B` a template as well?

Comment: Can you use `std::any b;`?

Comment: What about a base class for `A<N>` types? What about registering pointers to base type?

Comment: Depending on what exactly you are doing, you could have `A` inherit from a base class, and then in `B` you store a pointer to that base class.

Comment: Last resort is to make `class B` as template but I don't want to do that to preserve memory.  I can't use `std::any`.

Comment: @NathanOliver, if I do that, how can I get the templated object back from the base class pointer?

Comment: @MeCe That is a difficult problem to solve.  Mixing run-time and compile-time constructs is not very easy.

Comment: @MeCe you case use `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have gotten yourself into a bit of a catch-22 situation.

You can't hold a *templated* `A` inside of `B` without making `B` templated as well, eg:

```
template <int size>
class A {
public:
    int a[size];

    int getA(int n) {
       return a[n];
    }
};

template <int size>
class B {
public:
    A<size>* b;

    int getA(int n) {
        return b->getA(n);
    }

    void setB(A<size>* n) {
        b = n;
    }
};

int main()
{
    const int size1 = 10;

    A<size1> data1;
    B<size1> b1;
    
    b1.setB(&data1);
    int a = b1.getA(0);
}
```

Or by giving `A` a *non-templated* base class for `B` to hold, eg:

```
class A_base
{
    virtual ~A_base() {}
    virtual int getA(int n) = 0;
};

template <int size>
class A : public A_base {
public:
    int a[size];

    int getA(int n) {
       return a[n];
    }
};

class B {
public:
    A_base* b;

    int getA(int n) {
       return b->getA(n);
    }

    void setB(A_base* n) {
        b = n;
    }
};

int main()
{
    const int size1 = 10;

    A<size1> data1;
    B b1;
    
    b1.setB(&data1);
    int a = b1.getA(0);
}
```

Otherwise, you will have to make `B` just hold a `void*` pointer, and then require the caller to extract that `void*` and decide what to cast it to, eg:

```
template <int size>
class A {
public:
    int a[size];

    int getA(int n) {
       return a[n];
    }
};

class B {
public:
    void* b;

    void* getB() {
        return b;
    }

    void setB(void* n) {
        b = n;
    }
};

int main()
{
    const int size1 = 10;

    A<size1> data1;
    B b1;
    
    b1.setB(&data1);
    int a = static_cast< A<size1>* >(b1.getB())->getA(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you will want to pass the **size** from a constructor. Templates don't fit for this use case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I cannot pass `size` from the constructor since I don't want dynamic memory allocation on an embedded system.